# parsing xml document using cURL

Tags: php, xml, curl

I am trying to parse an xml document I created in a php file and outputted using

```
echo $xmlMysql->saveXML();
```

using cURL I send the information over, but when I try and parse it through using the following code.

```
 $xmlDoc = download_page($url);
  $dom = new DomDocument();
  $dom->load($xmlDoc);
  echo $dom->saveXML();
```

I get this error message,

```
<b>Warning</b>:  I/O warning : failed to load external entity 
^
```

any help with this would be much appreciated

Comment: Can you do a var_dump($xmlDoc) and see what you get?

Comment: I cut the error message short, but it included the cotents of the xml file I was sending over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if $xmlDoc is a string of XML that you're getting from an HTTP request, try using the loadXML method instead of just load method of your DomDocument object.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$dom = new DomDocument()
$dom->resolveExternals = false;
//...
```

to prevent external entities from being resolved. Of course, you may want to investigate which external entities are not being read. See also [`libxml_disable_entity_loader`](http://php.net/libxml_disable_entity_loader).

Answer (score -2):

Try the following code:

```
$dom = dom_import_simplexml(simplexml_load_string($response))->ownerDocument;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
echo '<PRE style="color:#000066;padding:10px;text-align:left">',htmlspecialchars($dom->saveXML()),'</PRE>';
```